# Индикаторы Карусели Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Коллеги.

Не подключаются индикаторы в Карусели Bootstrap 4. Не могу понять причину. Диспетчер показывает, что они есть в документе, но к ним не применены стили, все по нолям, применяю стили, индикаторы появляются, но не активны.
В чем причина и как исправить?
Код прилагается!

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li  data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li  data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li  data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="Images/carousel-image1.jpg" alt="Первый слайд">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="Images/carousel-image2.jpg" alt="Второй слайд">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="Images/carousel-image3.jpg" alt="Третий слайд">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Благодарен!

Answer (score -2):

Разобрался!)

Не была подключена одна из библиотек!